# Error when building custom filter in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am trying to build custom filter, that will change value for datetime that I have in UTC to user's timezone.

Since I am new to angularJs, I am not sure what should I do and where to register filter.

I have created filter as separated file named clientTime.js:

```
export default function(startDateTimeString) {

    let localTime  = this.$rootscope.momentTimezone.utc(startDateTimeString).toDate();
    localTime = this.$rootscope.momentTimezone(localTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

    return localTime;
}
```

As an argument to a function I am passing startDateTimeString, which is a string value of date-time in this format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'

In my HTML I have used filter like this:

```
<tr st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in dashCtrl.upcomingSessionsDisplay" ng-switch on="row.status"
    ng-click="dashCtrl.handleClickOnUpcomingSessions(row)" title="{{dashCtrl.tooltip(row)}}">
    <td>{{row.locationName}}</td>
    <td>{{row.startDateTimeString | clientTime}}</td>
</tr>
```

I have app.js where I am registering all components such as: services, interceptor, etc. So I figure it out that I should register filter there as well.

I have import filter like all other components:

```
import toastr from "toastr";
import _ from "underscore";
import momentTimezone from "moment-timezone";
import Components from "./components";
import Directives from "./shared/directives";
import Constants from "./shared/constants";
import Services from "./shared/services";
import Controllers from "./shared/controllers";
import AuthenticationInterceptor from "./shared/interceptors/AuthenticationInterceptor";
import ClientTime from "./shared/filters/clientTime";
```

And register it with the name 'clientTime':

```
angular
    .module("examino.main", ["ui.router", "smart-table", "ui.bootstrap", "ui.tree", Directives, Components, Constants, Services, Controllers])

    .run(function($rootScope, $state, AuthenticationService) {
        $rootScope._ = _;
        $rootScope.momentTimezone = momentTimezone;

        // register listener to watch route changes
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, params) {
            let goToStateName = "login";
            let isAccessTestSessionRoute = toState.name == "testEnv" || toState.name == "testEnv.dashboard" || toState.name == "sessionExpired";
            if(toState.name !== goToStateName && !AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated() && !isAccessTestSessionRoute) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go(goToStateName);
            }

            if(toState.redirectTo) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go(toState.redirectTo, params);
            }
        });
    })

    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");

        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("AuthenticationInterceptor");
    })
    .filter("clientTime", ClientTime)

    .service("AuthenticationInterceptor", AuthenticationInterceptor);

angular.bootstrap(document, ["examino.main"]);

//set toastr options
toastr.options = {
    positionClass: "toast-top-full-width"
};
```

I was pretty sure that this will work, but I get this error:

```
> vendor.js:26519 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:
> startDateTimeStringProvider <- startDateTimeString <- clientTimeFilter
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=startDateTimeStringProvider%20%3C-%20startDateTimeString%20%3C-%20clientTimeFilter
>     at vendor.js:12667
>     at vendor.js:17110
>     at Object.getService [as get] (vendor.js:17263)
>     at vendor.js:17115
>     at getService (vendor.js:17263)
>     at injectionArgs (vendor.js:17287)
>     at Object.invoke (vendor.js:17309)
>     at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (vendor.js:17156)
>     at Object.invoke (vendor.js:17317)
>     at vendor.js:17116
```

Now I completely understand what is the problem, I guess that angular do not understand dependency for filter. But I am not sure what is the solution for this.
I was starting from the idea that filter is similar to service or interceptor in a way that it is still an anonymous function, so I was thinking that this is the way for defining it. Can somebody share their experience with creating filters and possible solution to dependency problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in HOW you are defining your filter. The 'angular.filter' expects a **filter factory function**, according to the documentation (Writing your own filter is very easy: just register a new filter factory function with your module - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

So, your clientTime.js should be

```js
export default function() {
  return function(startDateTimeString) {

    let localTime  = this.$rootscope.momentTimezone.utc(startDateTimeString).toDate();
    localTime = this.$rootscope.momentTimezone(localTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

    return localTime;
  }
}
```

As you can see, the module now exports a function that returns your filtering function. Now it should work.

Comment: Yeah, you were right. Now I have other problem, $rootscope is not recognized and I was expecting that one to happened. I will have to find a way to pass $rootscope to filter, but that is a whole other question and problem. Thanks for helping out. @igor.araujo

Comment: You should inject $rootScope on your filter factory function: export default function($rootScope){ ... }
Do not forget to remove the 'this' variable from the filter code

Comment: that was the first thing I've did but it doesn't work. When I remove 'this' it says that $rootscope is not defined. Do I maybe need to do something like this.$rootscope = $rootscope? But I thing that that wont help as well... @ivan.araujo

Comment: @ivan.araujo my mistake, wrong spelling :/ it works. Thanks once again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used filters that much, but for all I remember, you need to create a filter component like so

```
angular.module('yourModule')
    .filter('clientTime', function() {
        // Your code
    });
```

And I didn't see it in your post. Maybe this is why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. I saw that way as well, but I guess it is a way to create filter inside app.js and I wanted to make it in a separated file, that's why I am missing that code. @trichetriche

Comment: Well you don't need to put everything in "app.js" as you said. I have like 30 to 40 JS files in my project, all containing a single component (controller, service, factory, constants, config ...) All you need to do is create a separated file, put your JS tag in your index.html file, and put your filter in the separated file. But you do need to do as stated.